# Analyzing synchronizer MTBF in Quartus

Tags: verilog, fpga, quartus, intel-fpga

I have a message from Quartus that it found synchronizer chains, but is unable to perform MTBF analysis on them. Yet, nothing is really explained in the manuals except how to recognize synchronizers so the tool does not optimize or retime them.

So far, all I/O have used `set_false_path`.

My best guess is,

1. I find the rise/fall time of an input.
2. I create virtual clock that indicates the frequency of the input toggle.

From this, the tool can deduce a meta-stable probability and then deduce from the length of the chain what the compound probability is.

```
Info (332114): Report Metastability: Found 12 synchronizer chains.
    Info (332114): The design MTBF is not calculated because there are no specified synchronizers in the design.
    Info (332114): Number of Synchronizer Chains Found: 12
    Info (332114): Shortest Synchronizer Chain: 2 Registers
    Info (332114): Fraction of Chains for which MTBFs Could Not be Calculated: 1.000
    Info (332114): Worst Case Available Settling Time: 8.863 ns
```

Is the SDC file with `set_input_delay` and virtual clocks the way to do this?  The message **there are no specified synchronizers in the design** doesn't tell you how to specify the synchronizer and I don't understand how it could calculate the MTBF unless it knows the frequency of time that the signal might be transitioning.

I have looked in the manual and the cook book.  The cook book seems like it describes real synchronous I/O and not a synchronizer for an asynchronous input.  In my particular instance, I have a quadrature encoded phase A/B where I could sample them as they are changing.  I want to make sure the chains are sufficiently sized for the rise fall of the signal.  I also know the minimum time between transitions (determined by a maximum speed), which I believe is the virtual clock period.

Comment: Related: [Metastability and double register approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40846222/solving-metastability-using-double-register-approach) and [How does 2ff ensure synchronization](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/237725/how-does-2-ff-synchronizer-ensure-proper-synchonization).

Comment: Also related: [Intel/Altera understanding Metastability](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/content-details/650346/understanding-metastability-in-fpgas.html) and [Cyclone I/O FF packing](https://www.01signal.com/vendor-specific/intel/io-ff-packing/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The report can be found in Timing analyzer under 'Report Metastability' near the bottom of the 'tasks' box/work panel.

Some of these are indeed false synchronizers and they are disabled with,

`set_instance_assignment -name SYNCHRONIZER_IDENTIFICATION OFF -to register_name`

The 'register_name' is listed under the 'Synchronization Node' in the 'Report Metastability' output.

> My best guess is,
> I find the rise/fall time of an input.
> I create virtual clock that indicates the frequency of the input toggle.

This confounds **slew** with MTBF and metastability.  The metastability is the time that the register needs to settle to a value.  The value maybe 'wrong'.  However, it is not changing while the clock is not active.  When a register/flip-flop is meta-stable, outputs referencing it may have different values resulting is unintended results due to logic optimizations.

Slew should be handled like a debounce circuit (slightly different than a synchronizer).  The slew rate through a forbidden range of the I/O gives a length of the debounce to prevent false transitions.

For example, 3.3-V LVTTL has the following voltage ranges,

- V<sub>il</sub> is -0.3 to 0.8V
- V<sub>ih</sub> is 1.7 to 3.6V

The time to transition from these voltages can be calculated in clocks and a packed register created to debounce this area.

```
   localparam DEBOUNCE_SIZE = 6;
   reg [DEBOUNCE_SIZE-1:0] signal_debounce = DEBOUNCE_SIZE{1'b0}};

   always @(posedge clock, negedge reset_n)
        if(!reset_n) begin
           signal_debounce <= {DEBOUNCE_SIZE{1'b0}};
        end
        else begin
           signal_debounce <= {signal, signal_debounce[DEBOUNCE_SIZE-1:1]};
           // - `&signal_debounce`    - all high
           // - `!(|signal_debounce)` - all low
           // - |signal_debounce     - at least one is high
         end
```

Signal is collected in the verilog packed array for several clocks.  The reduction operator can be used to test that all values are high or low.  This will filter values from the transitioning region used by a quadrature encoder or other related asynchronous inputs to prevent false triggers due to slew.

The above code is identical to a synchronizer chain, but all bits of the packed register are used, as opposed to just the 'low bit'.  Ie, if *t<sub>0</sub>* is now, then `signal_debounce[0]` refers to *t<sub>-6</sub>*.  This delay is a waste in normal logic, but is needed for a synchronizer.  If all taps (different signal times) are used, then the logic will never be optimized away.  So, the tool doesn't care about that case, but a developer should.

---

Information can be found in Chapter 3 or the 'Quartus Design Recommendations'.  Read the PDF and not google results from the web pages.  The PDF has an ordering that is not apparent in the web pages.
One mechanism is to specify a SYNCHRONIZER_TOOGLE_RATE to a register/flop-flop.

If I have the following,

```
set_instance_assignment -name SYNCHRONIZER_IDENTIFICATION FORCED -to register_name
set_instance_assignment -name SYNCHRONIZER_TOGGLE_RATE 32000 -to register_name
```

The report gives 1 billion years MTBF for a Cyclone V clocked at 100MHz.

The report is the same event Changing

- changing `SYNCHRONIZER_TOGGLE_RATE`
- using `FAST_INPUT_REGISTER ON`.
- using `INPUT_TRANSITION_TIME`.
- using virtual clocks and setting input times.

I think that the metastability is only for clock domain crossing (or synchronous I/O) or the lithography is so small that the Cyclone V has next to no change to go meta-stable when clocked at 100MHz.

The paper [Understanding Metastability in FPGAs](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/content-details/650346/understanding-metastability-in-fpgas.html) seems to suggest that some flip-flops have better metastability constants than others and this is controlled by process, etc.  It would seem reasonable that the I/O cell flip-flops would have the best properties.  However, I don't have documentation on this and can not get the timing tools to indicate any difference.  It maybe true with prior Altera/Intel logic elements, but is not true with more modern designs.

Also, the Intel staff said that having a reset value to the register would negate synchronizers, but this was not my experience.  Again, this might depend on RTL mapping.

Comment: If you happen to have an older technology, like Cyclone III and different clock rates, it would be interesting to see if the Quartus reports change with updates that I listed.  It is possible that a Cyclone V clocked at a faster rate might show changes in the MTBF analysis.  At any rate, it is difficult to know if the analysis is correct (I guess even if it does change).

Comment: In the example, if the slew rate is 60ns and the clock is 100MHz (10ns), then a count of six consecutive values should debounce.  Time outside Vil/Voh could also be used, if latency is also a concern.  Also, on the intel LEB, it can have from 2 to 7 inputs, so the reduction operators work best with debounce registers of this size.  If it is an extremely long period, you might go to some other structure (and not store all values).

Comment: Here is an example using a counter for longer debounce periods. https://alchitry.com/metastability-and-debouncing-verilog  However, it needs custom code to debounce/deslew both edges.  This is a must for mechanical inputs like a button press.  For slow electronics like opto-couplers or longer traces, the above code might be more appropriate.

Comment: **AN 366: Understanding I/O Output Timing for Altera Devices** is a paper which details the methodology to calculate I/O cell timing for use with the I/O register.  The paper is more concern with accurately describing output trace capacitance to alter Tco.